# How to monitor the HttpURLConnection PUT process

Tags: java, http, httpurlconnection

I have an app to upload files to a cloud service using HttpURLConnection:

```
    HttpURLConnection httpCon = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    httpCon.setDoOutput(true);
    httpCon.setRequestMethod("PUT");
    OutputStreamWriter out = new OutputStreamWriter(
        httpCon.getOutputStream());

    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("C:/Users/me/Pictures/_MG_9324.JPG");
    IOUtils.copy(fis,httpCon.getOutputStream());
    out.close();
    InputStream is= httpCon.getInputStream();
    IOUtils.copy(is,System.out);
```

The program didn't block at the first `IOUtils.copy`, instead, it blocks at the second `IOUtils.copy`.  My understanding is that the program blocks since the upload didn't complete.  So my questions during the upload, how do I monitor how much data is uploaded from client side?

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22523205/httpurlconnection-multipart-file-upload-with-progressbar/22526084#22526084

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The output is written to a `ByteArrayOutputStream` until you call `getInputStream()` or `getResponseCode()`, so that the Content-length header can be set correctly. So the second copy operation includes the upload. To avoid that, use chunked transfer mode.

Answer (score 1):

Don't wrap your OutputStream in an OutputStreamWriter, instead wrap your OutputStream in the below class. You can pass in a callback function that'll listen for the bytes being written.

```
public class CallbackEnabledOutputStream extends OutputStream {
    private OutputStreamListener outputStreamListener;
    private OutputStream realOutputStream;
    private int byteWriteThreshold;
    private int bytesWritten = 0;

    public CallbackEnabledOutputStream(OutputStreamListener outputStreamListener, OutputStream realOutputStream, int byteWriteThreshold) {
        super();
        this.outputStreamListener = outputStreamListener;
        this.realOutputStream = realOutputStream;
        this.byteWriteThreshold = byteWriteThreshold;
    }

    @Override
    public void write(int b) throws IOException {
        realOutputStream.write(b);
        bytesWritten++;
        if(bytesWritten > byteWriteThreshold) {
            outputStreamListener.bytesWritten(bytesWritten);
            bytesWritten = 0;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void flush() throws IOException {
        realOutputStream.flush();
    }

    @Override
    public void close() throws IOException {
        realOutputStream.flush();
    }
}
```

OutputStreamListener

```
public class OutputStreamListener {

    private int byteCount = 0;

    public void bytesWritten(int byteCount) {
        this.byteCount += byteCount;
    }

    public int getByteCount() {
        return byteCount;
    }
}
```